# Simple Question about grails domain class variable

Tags: variables, grails, groovy, constraints

So many sample show that need to declare each variable in next line such as below:

```
class RelationTest {

    String name
    String password
    String email
    String age
    String height
    String weight

    static constraints = {
        name maxSize:10,  blank: false
        password minSize:6, blank: false
        email email:true,blank: false
        age min: 18
        height()
        weight()
    }
}
```

But why not instead like this below:

```
class RelationTest {

    String name,password,email,age,height,weight

    static constraints = {
        name maxSize:10,  blank: false
        password minSize:6, blank: false
        email email:true,blank: false
        age min: 18
        height()
        weight()
    }
}
```

or it must be declare each variable on each line.?

Comment: I would strongly recommend adhering to the general coding principles, your colleges say thank you later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done for readability, and how historically properties of a Bean/Class were defined in Java. It's much easier to spot an individual property in the first example, rather than having to read the entire list on on one line.

Technically there is no difference in Groovy. It's just readability.